# Не работает скролл в таблице

Tags: html, css

Как можно реализовать scroll контента в Desktop версии на каждой вкладке в pop-up? В мобильной версии (media query) вкладки пропадают и все вливается в одну большую колону.

```
JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nax7pvsq/
```

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. в связи с ограничением кол-ва символов не смог опубликовать свой код тут, по этому использовал jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ответ банально прост, вам нужно в эту строку добавить z-index: 100;

```
.vfa-tabbed #tab-nav-5:checked~.tabs>div:nth-of-type(5),.vfa-tabbed #tab-nav-6:checked~.tabs>div:nth-of-type(6),.vfa-tabbed #tab-nav-7:checked~.tabs>div:nth-of-type(7){
z-index: 100; 
width:100%;
-webkit-transform:rotateX(0);
-moz-transform:rotateX(0);
-ms-transform:rotateX(0);
-o-transform:rotateX(0);
transform:rotateX(0);
opacity:1;
}
```

Так как вы работаете с absolute, то слои накладывались друг на друга и скролл не работал.

И при выборе новой вкладки, должен указываться z-index: выше предыдущего слоя

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает идеально!